# "You must have python installed and in your PATH" error when trying to install eclim

Tags: python, eclim

I am trying to install eclim, but I keep running into the error mentioned above. I've added the following lines to the ~/.bashrc :

```
PYTHONPATH=$HOME/lib/python
EDITOR=vim

export PYTHONPATH EDITOR
```

but I get the same error again and again

Comment: what do you get when you run `python` on your terminal?

Comment: Command 'python' not found, but python3 is working

Comment: run these commands, PYTHONPATH=$HOME/lib/python
EDITOR=vim export PYTHONPATH EDITOR
 and then check python within the same terminal and session

Comment: @GauriShankarBadola thank you. it worked

Comment: glad it worked...